# I want to delete the same part from the two -dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare the two arrangements of the following script to delete the duplicate arrangement.
I used the Filter and Includes function or for statement but failed.

What should I do?

```js
let ground = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
  [1,3,3,7,7,7,7,8,8,4,4,4,2,2,3,7,1],
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
]

let deleteBlock = [[1,3,3,7,7,7,7,8,8,4,4,4,2,2,3,7,1]]
```

I tried in this way

```js
let ans = ground.filter((r,idx) => {
    for(let i =0; i < deleteBlock.length;i++) {
     if(r === deleteBlock[i]) {
        ground.splice(idx, 1)
     }
    }
})
```

```js
ground.filter((r) => deleteBlock.forEach(ele=> r.includes(ele)))
```

Comment: _"I used the Filter and Includes function or for statement but failed."_ - please show this as a text-based [mcve]

Comment: First of  all, you should show some code of your attempts

Comment: use a json stringify hack :D

Comment: @evolutionxbox I also added the way I tried

Comment: @derpirscher I added the method I approached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `arrayEqual` function that compares two arrays

```
function arrayEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;  //adapt equality test if you have complex objects

  return true;
}
```

and then use it like the follows

```
let ground = [...];
let filtered = ground.filter(x => deleteBlock.every(y => !arrayEqual(x,y)));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!! But for some reason it doesn't work from me..

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't get that `deleteblock` is an array of arrays ...

Answer (score 1):

If you compare two arrays with the same properties you will always get false. For example, [1] === [1] always returns false since they are each a brand new array object with just identical contents.

So you should loop through both arrays and compare each of their properties one by one or in your case since I assume type is not essential you could deconstruct them and then compare the strings like this:

```
const filtered = ground.filter((row) => { return row.join() !== deleteBlock.join(); });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer!! It works fine! What if you want to change the original array, not the copied array?